# Construction of the morphism from the zig-zag lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

UPD: I'm not sure why i'm not getting any comments or votes, so I'm expanding a little bit below to make it easier to understand my question and make it more self-contained.

For reference I'm using the old edition of Lang's "Algebra", the one with homologies in their own chapter, but I'm sure it's there in the 2002 edition, too.

---

My question is about construction of the morphism that is the subject of the zig-zag lemma. Let $A$ be a ring, and consider three chain complexes of $A$-modules $(E', d)$, $(E, d)$ and $(E'', d)$ forming a short exact sequence $$0 \to E' \ \xrightarrow{f} \ E \ \xrightarrow{g} \ E'' \to 0.$$ From now on, following Lang, I will be dropping indices and parentheses where possible to make notation lighter. I will also denote submodules of cycles with a letter $Z$ and boundaries with the letter $B$ as usual. The homologies will be considered as graded modules given by $H_i(E) = Z_i / B_i$ and so on.

The problem is to prove that the formula $z'' \mapsto f^{-1} d g^{-1} z''$ defines a morphism $$\delta: H(E'') \to H(E'), \qquad \delta_i: Z''_i / B''_i \to Z'_{i+1} / B'_{i+1}.$$

Below is my completion of Lang's half page sketch of the explicit construction together with the proof of its correctness. The actual question is in the end.

---

Let $z'' \in Z''_i$. Then the set $f^{-1} d g^{-1} z'' \subset E'_{i+1}$ is not empty. Indeed, components of $g$ are surjective, so there is a $z \in E_i$ such that $gz = z''$. Since $0 = dz'' = dgz = gdz$, we have $dz \in \ker g = \operatorname{im} f \subset E_{i+1}$, therefore there is a $z' \in E'_{i+1}$ such that $fz' = dz$, and thus $f^{-1} d g^{-1} z'' \subset E'_{i+1}$ is not empty. Moreover, $f^{-1} d g^{-1} z'' \subset Z'_{i+1}$. Indeed, for all $z \in E_i$ such that $gz = z''$ and $z' \in E'_{i+1}$ such that $fz' = dz$ we have $fdz' = dfz' = d^2z = 0$.

Next, we prove that for all $z'_1, z'_2 \in f^{-1} d g^{-1} z'' $ we have $z'_1 - z'_2 \in B'_{i+1}$, or in other words that there is some $t \in E'_i$ such that $dt = z'_1 - z'_2$. We pick $z_1, z_2$ just like before, and observe that $f(z'_1 - z'_2) = d(z_1 - z_2)$. Since $g(z_1 - z_2) = z'' - z'' = 0$, then there is $t \in E'_i$ such that $ft = z_1 - z_2$, and we have $fdt = dft = d(z_1 - z_2) = f(z'_1 - z'_2)$. But every component of $f$ is injective, so we indeed have $dt = z'_1 - z'_2$.

Thus we have a mapping $\gamma_i: Z''_i \to Z'_{i+1} / B'_{i+1}$, $z'' \mapsto f^{-1} d g^{-1} z'' + B'_{i+1}$. We need to prove that it is a homomorphism. Let's prove that $\gamma_i(z''_1 + z''_2) = \gamma_i(z''_1) + \gamma_i(z''_2)$. Indeed, let's pick $z_1, z_2 \in E_i$ such that $gz_1 = z''_1$, $gz_2 = z''_2$. Then $g(z_1 + z_2) = z''_1 + z''_2$, and $d(z_1 + z_2) = d(z_1) + d(z_2)$. Let's pick $z'_1, z'_2 \in Z'_{i+1}$ such that $fz'_1 = dz_1$, $fz'_2 = dz_2$. Then $f(z'_1 + z'_2) = d(z_1 + z_2)$, thus if $z'_1 \in f^{-1} d g^{-1} z''_1$ and $z'_2 \in f^{-1} d g^{-1} z''_2$, then $z'_1 + z'_2 \in f^{-1} d g^{-1} (z''_1 + z''_2)$. But the classes of $z'_1, z'_2, z'_1 + z'_2$ modulo $B'_{i+1}$ is independent of the choice of $z_1, z_2$, and obviously $z'_1 + z'_2 + B'_{i+1} = (z'_1 + B'_{i+1}) + (z'_2 + B'_{i+1})$, and thus indeed $\gamma_i(z''_1 + z''_2) = \gamma_i(z''_1) + \gamma_i(z''_2)$. In the same way we prove that $\gamma_i(\alpha z') = \alpha \gamma_i(z')$ (I haven't actually done this, but it seems like it go the same way). Thus $\gamma_i$ is indeed a homomorphism.

Now all that's left to prove is that $B''_i \subset \ker \gamma_i$. Indeed, consider a $z'' \in B''_i$. Then there is a $w'' \in E''_{i-1}$ such that $dw'' = z''$, and a $w \in E_{i-1}$ such that $gw = w''$. Thus $z'' = dgw = gdw$. Thus there is a $z \in B_i$ such that $z = dw$ and $gz = z''$. Obviously, $dz = 0$, and because every component of $f$ is an injection, there is only one $z'_0 \in Z'_{i+1}$ such that $fz'_0 = dz = 0$, and it is $z'_0 = 0$. But then for all $z' \in f^{-1} d g^{-1} z''$ we have $z' - z'_0 = z' \in B'_{i+1}$, and thus $f^{-1} d g^{-1} z'' \subset B'_{i+1}$, as was to be proved.

Now by the homomorphism theorem $\gamma_i$ uniquely factors through some $\delta_i: Z''_i / B''_i \to Z'_{i+1} / B'_{i+1}$, and this is what we needed to construct.

---

My two questions are:

1. Is this proof correct and complete?
2. Was there a shortcut that I missed?

UPD: I understand that this is not a delightful question to attempt to answer. So God giveth, God taketh: I'll award the bounty to the most serious flaw found, or to Dylan if none are found.

Comment: This looks good to me!

Comment: I didn't see this question before and I agree with Dylan. Your proof is correct but, as you will be certainly be aware of, not quite complete, since you didn't check that $\gamma$ commutes with scalar multiplication. I don't think there is any significant short cut (using this approach). You should now check that you get a long exact sequence in homology...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks good to me, and I doubt that there's going to be a shorter proof via diagram chasing.

Since I think an answer should be more informative than this, I've uploaded a proof of the snake lemma for chain complexes of vector spaces [at Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/63147908/Snake-Lemma). These are notes I took on a lecture given by [Kevin Costello](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~costello/) — any errors are surely mine. His proof is slightly more conceptual and you might like it. Unfortunately, I haven't had time to think about whether this can be adapted to the general case; in particular, at some point he chooses a splitting of each $0 \to A^i \to B^i \to C^i \to 0$ and this is often unavailable in the general case.

Comment: The proof in your notes is neat but unfortunately it doesn't really generalize directly. However, what you can do is use the [mapping cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(homological_algebra)) of the map $\alpha: A \to B$ and that gives a degree-wise split sequence $B \to C(\alpha) \to A[1]$ to which you can apply the argument in your notes. Furthermore there is a natural cochain map $C(\alpha) \to C$ which is a quasi-isomorphism (isomorphism in homology) which is in the end responsible for he long exact seq. But fleshing out all this is certainly as long as Alexey's argument.